# What are the technics to create flowing liquid static geometry?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, sculpting, fluid-simulation, simulation-nodes

I need to create something like this – chunky & very pronounced liquidy abstract geometry based on a restricted surface. Simply put, I want to create the roof for the cartoon house looking exactly like that.

[image]

Please recommend the approach you personally would use to achieve similar result?

Comment: if you wanna have it exactly (!!) like that, you have to sculpt it. or you need hundred years with mantaflow to get it exactly like that because of try and error which i don't recommend.

Comment: got it) and if i want not exactly like that but visually similar – what would you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some starting approach:

[image]

[image]

You can build on top of that:

- aligning curves to topology, e.g. using "Shortest Path" node, and maybe putting a lot of weight on horizontal edges
- varying spline thickness
- using a simulation to adjust local thickness to avoid too much overlap
- remeshing and blurring color
- varying thickness along a spline in a ping-pong fashion, maybe even raising the thickness to a power > 1 to give a more rounded, bulgy local thicknesses, to make it look like clumping of a liquid

and the list goes on...

Comment: I think it looks a bit like a Santa's hat, isn't it?

Comment: @lemon damn you're right https://i.imgur.com/C8dCe6i.png

Comment: amazing flow! I'll try this thing, thank you for the details <3